# Text not appearing in Safari?

Tags: css, text, safari

I am having trouble making http://jackwaghorn.com/#popup usable in Safari. Chrome hasn't been a problem but when it comes to text appearing in an overlay DIV - nothing comes through in Safari. Unless you press 'new tab'.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbUAf.jpg

Comment: please provide sample code you have html/css

Answer (score 0):

You already found the problem. We call it Safari. If you use Safari for Windows you cannot optimize the webpage for this.